# Mutliplication rule vs. complement principle

Tags: probability

If you roll four dice, what is the probability that there will be at least two dice showing the same number? I suppose the answer is 1 - [(6*5*4*3)/6^4] using the complement principle. But would how do I do this 'normally'? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you did work this "normally", but if you wanted to work this without using the complement principle you could break it into cases:

1) If all 4 dice are the same, there are 6 possibilities.

2) If exactly 3 of the dice are the same, there are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to choose the 3 that will be the same, 6 ways to choose their number, and 5 ways to choose the number of the remaining die.

3) If there are exactly 2 dice that are the same, there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose the 2 that will be the same, 6 ways to choose their number, 5 ways to choose the number for the first die that is left, and 4 ways to choose the number for the last die.

4) If there are 2 pairs of dice that are the same, there are 3 ways to choose the "partner" for the first die, 6 ways to choose the number for this pair, and 5 ways to choose the number for the other pair.

This gives a probability of $\displaystyle\frac{6+4\cdot6\cdot5+6\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4+3\cdot6\cdot5}{6^4}=\frac{936}{6^4}=\frac{13}{18}$.